# How to take snapshot from Google Map in Android with map View in Android fragment

Tags: snapshot

We want to take a snapshot from Google Map in Fragment and not save into External Storage it send through retrofit API, and also I have done but facing one problem image only get in black color not show map on imageview.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener;
    private TextView resutText;
    private ImageView marker;
    ImageView iconnn;
    private LatLng mCenterLatLong;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22)
            setStatusBarTranslucent(false);
        else
            setStatusBarTranslucent(true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        resutText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dragg_result);
        marker=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.marker1);
        iconnn=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.iconnn);


        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        configureCameraIdle();

    }

    private void configureCameraIdle() {
        onCameraIdleListener = new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {

                LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);

                CameraUpdate zoom= CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

                mMap.moveCamera(center);
                mMap.animateCamera(zoom);



                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        String locality = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        if (!locality.isEmpty() && !country.isEmpty())
                            resutText.setText(locality + "  " + country);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                float zoomLevel = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
                //use zoomLevel value..
            }


        });

        new CountDownTimer (5000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                captureScreen();
            }
        }.start ();


    }

    public void captureScreen()
    {
        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               String  filePath = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";



               iconnn.setImageBitmap (snapshot);


            }
        };

        mMap.snapshot(callback);
    }



    protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }`` SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener;
    private TextView resutText;
    private ImageView marker;
    ImageView iconnn;
    private LatLng mCenterLatLong;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22)
            setStatusBarTranslucent(false);
        else
            setStatusBarTranslucent(true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        resutText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dragg_result);
        marker=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.marker1);
        iconnn=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.iconnn);


        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        configureCameraIdle();

    }

    private void configureCameraIdle() {
        onCameraIdleListener = new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {

                LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);

                CameraUpdate zoom= CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

                mMap.moveCamera(center);
                mMap.animateCamera(zoom);



                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        String locality = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        if (!locality.isEmpty() && !country.isEmpty())
                            resutText.setText(locality + "  " + country);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                float zoomLevel = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
                //use zoomLevel value..
            }


        });

        new CountDownTimer (5000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                captureScreen();
            }
        }.start ();


    }

    public void captureScreen()
    {
        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               String  filePath = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";



               iconnn.setImageBitmap (snapshot);


            }
        };

        mMap.snapshot(callback);
    }



    protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }

}
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.